# Why isn't a generic type recognized as its derived type when passed as a generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm having some trouble trying to wrap my head around how generic parameters are expected to work in the following code scenario:

```
class Predicate { }
class BarPredicate : Predicate { }
class FooPredicate : Predicate { }

class Program {

    private static IPredicateHandler<T> Create<T>(T t) where T : Predicate
    {
        // T is always Predicate
    } 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Predicate>() {new FooPredicate(), new BarPredicate()};
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var o = Create(item);
        }
    }
}
```

When invoking Create, the generic type T is always set to Predicate instead of the derived type. I understand that this is because the objects in the list are stored as Predicates. However, I expected that the derived type would be recognized when invoking Create. Why doesn't this happen here? Is there any way I can get the derived type (FooPredicate/BarPredicate) to be passed into Create instead of the base type (Predicate)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to perform overload resolution using the dynamic type is with the `dynamic` keyword.

```
foreach (dynamic item in list) {
    dynamic o = Create(item);
}
```

Comment: +1. And it really creates correct types - thanks! (so much easier than `MakeGenericType` code).

Comment: Agreed. It's a nifty trick. Trying to figure out exactly how (and why) it works!

Comment: @j0k: It works because `dynamic` means "start the compiler again at runtime and re-analyze this expression as though the *runtime* types were the types that were given to the compiler in the original expression".  Yes, it is every bit as fast as that sounds.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have list of `Predicates`. When you get element from list it is still only a base class. In runtime it will be a derived class, but generic works durring compilation.

Comment: I knew that, but it didn't come to mind. Thanks for the reminder!